# Broken 2009 Town and Country power sliding door

Tags: chrysler, door, town-and-country

The passenger side power sliding door will not work aside from manually opening closing it. The wire enclosure appears to be ok, it seems to be an issue with the components toward the back of the door as compared to the functioning driver side door. I'm at a loss for even what to refer to these parts as to do a reasonable search online. Most of the videos I see online refer to the wires in the enclosure getting bent over time, but I do not believe that is the case here - I'm pretty sure something mechanical is not right. In addition, after I close the manually, I will often get a series of clicks in the door before it stops. Any pointers?

Comment: When you say "wire enclosure", are you talking about the bundle which is in the track at the bottom door frame? (At least I believe that's where it's located in the Dodge/Chrysler vans ...)

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words @toddkitta